# App crashes after closing it

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I have a very odd problem with my app!

I've been programming it on bluestacks and everything was fine - no crashes or what so ever. When I moved the apk to my phone it also worked fine **until I closed the app** - which caused a crash I don't know how to obtain.

this made me suspect that my problem has to do with the SurfaceView I'm using, but I don't know what might be the problem that causes the crashes.

**here is onCreate:**

```
GameView g;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         g=new GameView(this);
        setContentView(g);
    }
```

**here is how I create the surfaceview:**

```
gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
        this.requestFocus();
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                boolean retry = true;
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                while (retry) {
                    try {
                        gameLoopThread.join();
                        retry = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                gameLoopThread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
            }
        });
    }
```

**and here is the thread:**

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

public class GameLoopThread extends Thread {
       static final long FPS = 60;
       private GameView view;
       private boolean running = false;

       public GameLoopThread(GameView view) {
             this.view = view;
       }

       public void setRunning(boolean run) {
             running = run;
       }

       @SuppressLint("WrongCall") @Override
       public void run() {
             long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
             long startTime;
             long sleepTime;
             while (running) {
                    Canvas c = null;
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    try {
                           c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                           synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                                  view.onDraw(c);
                           }
                    } finally {
                           if (c != null) {
                                  view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                           }
                    }
                    sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                    try {
                           //if (sleepTime > 0)
                               //   sleep(sleepTime);
                          // else
                                  //sleep(10);
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
             }
       }
}
```

I didn't touch ondestroy or onstop, so the problem has to be somewhere in surfaceview I suspect.

Edit:
whole gameview:

```
public GameView(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(c);
        this.c = c;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        ScoreParticleP=new PointF();
        NewScoreParticleP=new PointF();
        int srcWidth = options.outWidth;
        int srcHeight = options.outHeight;
        //it=blocks.iterator();
        // Decode with inSampleSize
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        this.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        this.screenw = display.getWidth();
        this.screenh = display.getHeight();
        this.differencew = (double) screenw / normalw;
        this.differenceh = (double) screenh / normalh;
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.nyan);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.remix);
        mediaPlayer2.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer3 = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.weed);
        mediaPlayer3.setLooping(true);
        SharedPreferences prefs2 = c.getSharedPreferences("Sp.game.spiceinspace", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        counter2=prefs2.getInt("score", 0);
        this.sprite = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.sprite,options);
        this.sprite = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sprite, sprite.getWidth() * 3,
                sprite.getHeight() * 3, false);
        this.heart=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.heart);
        this.heart=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(heart, heart.getWidth() * 3,
                heart.getHeight() * 3, false);
        currentSpeed = new PointF(0, 0);
        currentDirection = new Point(0, 0);
        currentPosition = new Point(350, 350);
        this.background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.space);
        this.background=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, background.getWidth()*5, background.getHeight()*5, false);
        this.lost= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.gameover);
        this.lostNew= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.gameovernew);
        lostNew=FitAllDevices(lostNew);
        lost=FitAllDevices(lost);
        this.alien = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.mob_alien);
        this.coin = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.item_coin);
        partic=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.particle_star);
        partic=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(partic, partic.getWidth()*2, partic.getHeight()*2, false);
        this.alien = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(alien, alien.getWidth() * 3,
                alien.getHeight() * 3, false);
        asteroid=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.mob_astroid);
        asteroid=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(asteroid, asteroid.getWidth() * 3,
                asteroid.getHeight() * 3, false);
        goldasteroid=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.mob_goldastroid);
        goldasteroid=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(goldasteroid, goldasteroid.getWidth() * 3,
                goldasteroid.getHeight() * 3, false);
        mushroom=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.item_mushroom);
        mushroom=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mushroom, mushroom.getWidth() * 4,
                mushroom.getHeight() * 4, false);
        coin=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(coin, coin.getWidth() * 2,
                coin.getHeight() * 2, false);
        drug=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.item_not);
        drug=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(drug, drug.getWidth() * 4,
                drug.getHeight() * 4, false);
        rocket=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.item_rocket);
        rocket=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rocket, rocket.getWidth() * 4,
                rocket.getHeight() * 4, false);

        alien = FitAllDevices(alien);
        mushroom = FitAllDevices(mushroom);
        drug = FitAllDevices(drug);
        rocket = FitAllDevices(rocket);
        asteroid=FitAllDevices(asteroid);
        goldasteroid=FitAllDevices(goldasteroid);
        sprite = FitAllDevices(sprite);
        heart=FitAllDevices(heart);
        player = new Spicy(sprite,heart);
        hit= soundPool.load(c, R.raw.hit, 1);
        pass= soundPool.load(c, R.raw.win, 1);
        remix= soundPool.load(c, R.raw.remix, 1);
        destroy= soundPool.load(c, R.raw.destroy, 1);
        aliensound= soundPool.load(c, R.raw.alien, 1);
        gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
        this.requestFocus();
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                boolean retry = true;
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                while (retry) {
                    try {
                        gameLoopThread.join();
                        retry = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                gameLoopThread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
            }
        });
    }
```

***edit 2***
I found the logcat of the phone, here is the crash:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the screen grab of your logcat output, you're getting an UnsupportedOperationException from [java.lang.Thread.stop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()). This is the behavior on all versions of Android, as that call is deprecated and does nothing but throw an exception.

It's being called from your code (`Sp.game.spiceinspace.MainActivity.onStop`, MainActivity.java line 26).  You need to stop doing that, and end the thread some other way.

It's possible that the app is crashing on the emulator as well, but for some reason the crash isn't being brought to your attention.